# VirtualMachineError in overriding View.layout(...)

Tags: android, android-view, dalvik, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-inflate

Android throws fatal error then I inflating class, which has overridden method:

```
Class MyButton extends Button {
    ....
    @Override
    public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.layout(l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```

Doesn't matter if I comment my code or not. Application works only I remove this overridden function.

Error:

```
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363): java.lang.VirtualMachineError
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:200)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:8807)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at com.eee.android.activities.Screen1.addSubject(Screen1.java:372)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at com.xxx.android.activities.Screen1.parseData(Screen1.java:348)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at com.xxx.android.activities.Screen1.initalizeData(Screen1.java:178)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at com.xxx.android.activities.Screen1.onResume(Screen1.java:139)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-18 13:45:43.809: E/AndroidRuntime(13363):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas?

**Edit: I fixed my problem in other way. Just moved drawable generation code to other event. But I am interesting, why I still get VirtualMachineError if I try to override this method.**

UPDATE: if I `MyButton` extends from `View`, I got same error.

UPDATE:

I found additional messages:

```
09-19 09:24:43.789: W/dalvikvm(17401): Method Lcom/videoclasse/android/widgets/SubjectButton;.layout overrides final Landroid/view/View;.layout
09-19 09:24:43.789: W/dalvikvm(17401): failed creating vtable
09-19 09:24:43.789: W/dalvikvm(17401): Link of class 'Lcom/videoclasse/android/widgets/SubjectButton;' failed
```

At last I found in android 2.3.3. View.layout was defined:

```
public final void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    boolean changed = setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    if (changed || (mPrivateFlags & LAYOUT_REQUIRED) == LAYOUT_REQUIRED) {
        if (ViewDebug.TRACE_HIERARCHY) {
            ViewDebug.trace(this, ViewDebug.HierarchyTraceType.ON_LAYOUT);
        }

        onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        mPrivateFlags &= ~LAYOUT_REQUIRED;
    }
    mPrivateFlags &= ~FORCE_LAYOUT;
}
```

sorry for stupid question.

Comment: could you please post the real code? `Class MyButton` will not even compile...

Comment: Full code: http://pastebin.com/phpE6z4k

Comment: `if (hasWindowFocus);` is a dangerous typo, the `;` ends the if condition so your redraw will be always executed... anyway if you remove the `layout()` method, you don't get this error?

Comment: @WarrenFaith thanks for tip. Yes, then I remove layout(...) program run well. Compiler and IDE don't give any warnings.

Comment: Are there any other messages in logcat shortly before/after this that might be relevant to the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android 2.3.3. `View.layout` is defined as final. But in android 4.0 this functions is no more final. Reason I got this error is because I am using 4.0.0 builder.

Thanks to @WarrenFaith for founded mistype in the code, and very thanks to @JesusFreke for given direction where search more info.